# Change DIV color when an other DIV is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

as you can see on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C8B8g/7/ I have 2 button (= 2 divs) "The region" and "The source". Each div gets highlighted (blue background) on mouse over (thanks to stackoverflow contributors cause I'm still very bad in JS).

I've noticed that users don't actually realize that these are buttons so what I would like to do is to have the first DIV containing the text "Our region" to be highlighted with the blue background by default and only come back to white background when the other div containing the text "our source" is clicked (in that case "our source" background would turn blue). Made some testing using "current" in CSS but without success...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:
Updated:
[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/C8B8g/24/)

```
$('.activity-title a:first').css({'background-color':'#f00','color':'#fff'});
//for setting first button highlighted by default,
//don't forgot to define document.ready before this

$('.activity-title a').click(function() {
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

    $('.activity-title a').css({'background-color':'#fff','color':'#467FD9'});
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#f00','color':'#fff'});

    $('.textzone:visible').stop().fadeOut(500, function () {
    //don't forgot to add stop() for preventing repeat click conflict
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(500);
    });

    return false;

});​
```

Comment: Thanks - It works Great! Is there a way to have the first button highlighted by default? (since the text zone on the right is visible, that would help people understand that each button is associated to a text zone)

Comment: @Greg i updated my answer mate, you can assign these css values to an class or id, and use removeClass/addClass methods but you asked how to change css with jQuery, so i answered this way.

Answer (score 5):

Add style for selected div

```
.source-selected {
    background-color:#00F;
}
```

Add this class to your default div.

Add this lines to your click handler (updated)

```
if(!$(this).closest('.source-title-box').hasClass('source-selected'))
{
    $('.source-title-box').toggleClass('source-selected');
}
```

​Try updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmvcQ/1

Comment: I like your approach better as it avoids inline css. However this will apply the class alternately, it won't matter which link you click on. You would need to add in another line before the one you added, something like this:

`$('.source-selected').toggleClass('source-selected');`

Comment: You would probably also want to check for the closest('.source-title-box'), as your code selects all of them.

Comment: You are right, I was trying to be fast ;) I have fixed the fiddle and updated answer according to your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I decided to post an answer as there were some parts of your code that I wanted to address.

First of all, instead of doing a `return false;` at the end, you can use the jQuery `event.preventDefault();` function. The end result is basically the same, however doing it this way we can use jQuery to tell the anchor to do nothing at the very start, before we run any other code.

My updated Javascript code:

```
$('.source-title-box a').click(function(event) {

    // Stop the default anchor behaviour
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Lets check if the clicked link is already active
    // And if it is active, don't let them click it!
    if($(this).closest('div').hasClass('active')) {
        return false;   
    }

    // Now lets remove any active classes that exist
    $('.active').toggleClass('active');

    // And apply an active class to the clicked buttons
    // parent div
    $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('active');

    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

    $('.textzone:visible').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

The CSS I added:

```
.active {
    background-color:#467FD9;
    color:#fff;   

}
.active a {
    cursor:default;  /* Don't show the hand cursor */
    color:#fff;  
}
```

A Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dmvcQ/3/

I'm not sure if the current HTML markup has some other purpose in mind, but the current styles and functionality could be achieved with just a `<a href="#" data-region="source-region">Our region</a>` you don't need to wrap them in a `<div>` and a `<span>`.

For example here is the same code, with just anchor tags: http://jsfiddle.net/dmvcQ/7/

Let me know if you have any questions regarding the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeemusu! For some reason in live environment (click on page "the source" here http://goo.gl/fOHGN ) the first 'button' doesnt get highlighted by default like on jsfiddle. Would you know why? Thanks

Comment: Did you add the active class to the html element that is to show as selected by default. Check my Js fiddle to see how i've set it.

Comment: Oops, I missed that one - it's OK now, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
try with this exemple:
<div id="target">
 Test1
</div>
<div id="other">
  Test2
</div>

<script>
$("#target").click(function() {
  $('#target').css({'background':'blue'});
 $('#other').css({'background':'white'});
});

$("#other").click(function() {
  $('#other').css({'background':'blue'});
  $('#target').css({'background':'white'});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it mainly jquery

A working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/razmig/GhbjS/

```
$('.activity-title a:first').css({
    "background-color": "#467FD9",
    "color": "#fff"
});


$('.activity-title a').mouseover(function() {
    $('.activity-title a').css({
        "background-color": "#fff",
        "color": "#467FD9"
    });
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "#467FD9",
        "color": "#fff"
    });

});

$('.activity-title a').click(function() {
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

    $('.textzone:visible').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(2000);
    });

    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the working example. I noticed that you change the html for href="#". Unfortunately in my case (one page layout with 1 div per section) that does not work (clicking on the button makes the page to scroll up to the top.

Comment: just add href="javascript:void(0)" or in jquery u can use event.preventDefault();